# Docker in docker implementation

Tags: docker, image, docker-in-docker

I have a use case where I need to run docker in docker, however I want to know if it’s possible to run docker commands without my pod image having the docker binary installed?
I’ve mounted docker.sock on my pod however it only works if  the docker binary is installed in my pod image, please let me know if it’s possible to run docker commands without my image having docker installed ?

I’ve tried installing the docker binary on my image and in that case it worked.

Comment: If you want to use the `docker` command, then the command needs to be installed in your pod. If you have access to the docker socket, you can of course interact with it directly using e.g. `curl`, Python, etc. However, note that in all of the above cases you are not technically running "docker in docker", because you are still interacting with the docker daemon on your host.

Comment: If you have access to a DinD service (maybe your client container and the DinD container are being launched from the same Compose file) then you can interact with it via any of the paths @larsks suggests, setting `$DOCKER_HOST` accordingly.  You don't specifically need the `docker` CLI but you need some sort of client code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.